# Sokal and Sneath Function Distance in R

Tags: r, function, distance

This is more of a function problem. So i have the Sokal and Sneath distance, for binary vectors:

```
d(xi,xj)=a/(a+2*(b+c))
```

where, a=#(xik=xjk=1), b=#(xik=0 and xjk=1) and c=#(xik=1 and xjk=0). k is the number of columns of the matrix, and # indicates the number of times of the event.

Could you give me hints and tips. Thank you.

I have written a,b,c as

```
a=sum(x[i]==x[j]==1)

b=sum((x[i]==0)&&(x[j]==0]))

c=sum((x[i]==1)&&(x[j]==1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:

```
SSD<- function(x) {
      x<-as.matrix(x) #convert to matrix 
      dist.matrix<- matrix(0,nrow(x),nrow(x)) #creates empty matrix
      for (i in 1:nrow(x)) { #iterate the data rows over i
        for (j in 1:nrow(x)) { #iterate the data rows over j
          a<- 0 #empty|
          b<- 0 #empty|=> to populate later on
          c<- 0 #empty|
          for (k in 1:ncol(x)) { #iterate the data over columns
          if (((x)[i,k]==1)&((x)[j,k]==1)) { #first assumption to hold
              a<-a+1 #summing the ones that hold the case
            }else if (((x)[i,k]==0)&((x)[j,k]==1)) { #second assumption
              b<-b+1 #summing the ones that hold the case
            } else if (((x)[i,k]==1)&((x)[j,k]==0)) { #third assumption
              c<-c+1 #summing the ones that hold the case
            }
          }
          dist.matrix[i,j]<-a/(a+2*(b+c)) #populate the matrix by the formula given 
        }
      }  
      library(xtable)
      return(xtable(dist.matrix))
    }
```